# How to make headlessMediaPlayer with vlcj version 4.7.0 for audio Streaming?

Tags: java, streaming, audio-streaming, vlcj

I am trying to make audio-streaming Server using vlcj java **version 4.7.0** 
So I download the jars from https://jar-download.com/?search_box=vlcj 
I run this example that I found out on github :

```
void start(String address, int port, String music,String type) throws Exception {
            String media = music;
            String options = getRtspStreamformat(address, port, type);
    
            MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
            HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
            mediaPlayer.playMedia(media,
                options,
                ":sout-all",
                ":sout-keep"
            );
}
```

and my Eclipse IDE was unable to find `HeadlessMediaPlayer` class even that I added all the jars

Comment: There's too much wrong here really. You say you're using vlcj 4.7.0, but the example you found is clearly not vlcj 4.x. It might be some earlier version, I honestly can't remember. I'd recommend you use Maven to pull in the jar files for vlcj, and then look at the vlcj examples that ARE for 4.x. After that maybe revise your question a bit if there's still a problem

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, can you refer me to example of how to stream a media file (RTSP or HTTP) using vlcj 4.x ?